Yahboom Dofbot: no ik for grasp pose using ros2 & moveit task constructor
I took the URDF and SRDF provided by Yahboom and am trying to extend them so the gripper is properly modeled and I can address it. The fingers are geared together so there is only one servo to control but I cannot figure out how to model that in the SRDF.
I think I am having a problem with the arm being always in collision. I am using MoveIt Task Constructor and when I look in RViz for why planning fails, it fails on the "grasp pose IK" phase with "no IK solution" for every generated pose.
The urdf is here: https://github.com/thatsnotright/dofbot/blob/main/dofbot/urdf/robot.urdf
I would appreciate any advice. I have tried making a "Ready" pose which is nearly at the target cylinder and it still fails to plan. Using the motion planner in rviz I can create a joint trajectory plan and it can grasp the cylinder so it's reachable.
